# Dependency Inversion: How to best manage versioning of your Abstractions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, abstraction, dependency-inversion

**How to version abstractions in .Net when applying Dependency Inversion in a high code-reuse environment**

I am interested in shifting toward using Dependency Inversion in .Net, but have come across something that puzzles me.
I don’t believe it is tied to a particular method or provider of DIP, but more a fundamental issue that perhaps others have solved.  The issue I'm solving for is best laid out step-by-step as scenario below.

**Assumption / Restriction**

A considerable assumption or restriction to put out there up front, is that my development team has stuck with a rule of keeping our deployed assemblies to one and only one Assembly Version, specifically version “1.0.0.0”. 
Thus far, we have not supported having more than this one Assembly Version of any given assembly we’ve developed deployed on a server for the sake of simplicity.  This may be limiting, and there may be many good reasons to move away from this, but never the less, it is currently a rule we work with.  So with this practice in mind, continue below.

**Scenario**

- You have an IDoStuff interface contained in an abstraction assembly
  Stuff.Abstractions.dll with 2 methods.
- You compile component A.dll
  with a class explicitly implementing IDoStuff with 2 methods.
- You move A.dll to production use, Assembly Version 1.0.0.0, Assembly File
  version 1.0.0.0.
- You move Interface.dll to prod, Assembly Version
  1.0.0.0, Assembly File version 1.0.0.0.
- Everything works fine.  Time passes by.
- You add another method (“DoMoreStuff” for example) to the IDoStuff interface so that a different Component B can call it.
  (Keeping Interface Segregation OO principle in mind, let’s say the DoMoreStuff method makes sense to be in this relatively small IDoStuff interface.)
- You now have IDoStuff with 3 methods in Stuff.Abstractions.dll, and you’ve built Component B to use the new 3rd method.
- You move Stuff.Abstractions.dll to production use (upgrade it), Assembly Version 1.0.0.0, Assembly File Version 1.0.0.1.
  (note that the file version is incremented, but the assembly version and therefore the strong name stays the same)
- You move B.dll to production use, Assembly Version 1.0.0.0, Assembly File version 1.0.0.17.
- You don’t do a thing to A.dll.  You figure there are no changes needed at this time.

Now you call code that attempts to execute A.dll on the same production server where it had been working before. At runtime the Dependency Inversion framework resolves the IDoStuff interface to a class inside A.dll and tries to create it.
Problem is that class in A.dll implemented the now ***extinct*** 2-method IDoStuff interface.  As one might expect, you will get an exception like this one:

***Method ‘DoMoreStuff’ in type ‘the IDoStuff Class inside A.dll’ from assembly ‘strong name of assembly A.dll’ does not have an implementation.***

I am presented with two ways that I can think of to deal with this scenario when I’d have to add a method to an existing interface:

1)  Update every functionality-providing assembly that uses Stuff.Abstractions.dll to have an implementation of the new ‘DoMoreStuff’ method.
This seems like doing things the hard way, but in a brute-force way would painfully work.

2)  Bend the Assumption / Restriction stated above and start allowing more than one Assembly Version to exist (at least for abstraction definition assemblies).
This would be a bit different, and make for a few more assemblies on our servers, but it should allow for the following end state:

A.dll depends on stuff.abstractions.dll, Assembly Version 1.0.0.0, Assembly File Version 1.0.0.22 (AFV doesn’t matter other than identifying the build)
B.dll depends on stuff.abstractions.dll, Assembly Version 1.0.0.1, Assembly File Version 1.0.0.23 (AFV doesn’t matter other than identifying the build)
Both happily able to execute on the same server.

If both versions of stuff.abstractions.dll are installed on the server, then everything should get along fine.  A.dll should not need to be altered either.  Whenever it needs mods next, you’d have the option to implement a stub and upgrade the interface, or do nothing.  Perhaps it would be better to keep it down to the 2 methods it had access to in the first place if it only ever needed them.
    As a side benefit, we’d know that anything referencing stuff.abstractions.dll, version 1.0.0.0 only has access to the 2 interface methods, whereas users of 1.0.0.1 have access to 3 methods.

**Is there a better way or an accepted deployment pattern for versioning abstractions?**

Are there better ways to deal with versioning abstractions if you’re trying to implement a Dependency Inversion scheme in .Net?
Where you have one monolithic application, it seems simple since it’s all contained – just update the interface users and implementers.
The particular scenario I’m trying to solve for is a high code-reuse environment where you have lots of components that depend on lots of components.  Dependency Inversion will really help break things up and make Unit Testing feel a lot less like System Testing (due to layers of tight coupling).

Comment: In most circumstances you would just have your abstractions (interfaces) in a single project, then implementations of those interfaces in another project (and potentially more projects for the different implementations).  You would use an IOC container to manage the bindings.  When code is deployed it would be deployed all in one swoop so the assuembly version would be the same, you would have different profiles for the bindings depending on the environment.  So if you were in prod, bind ClassA to IInterfaceA, but if you are in dev bind MockA to IInterfaceA, etc etc.

Comment: While not 100% accurate, for your purposes, DI has absolutely nothing to do with assembly versioning.  Think of DI as a bridging container across different layers (assemblies in your case).  As long as the solution compiles it'll work regardless of version.

Comment: Your real issue here is that you should never, never simply replace a `dll` in prod without passing through a CI/build pipeline. Whatever app you are deploying should be built as a WHOLE. That will solve your problems because the dude updating dependency `B` will have to update dependency `A`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem may be that you're depending directly on interfaces which were designed with a broader purpose in mind. You can mitigate the problem by having your classes depend on abstractions which were created for them.

If you define interfaces as needed to represent the dependencies of your classes rather than depending on external interfaces, you'll never have to worry about implementing interface members that you don't need.

Suppose I'm writing a class that involves an order shipment, and I realize that I'm going to need to validate the address. I might have a library or a service that performs such validations. But I wouldn't necessarily want to just inject that interface right into my class, because now my class has an outward-facing dependency. If that interface grows, I'm potentially violating the Interface Segregation Principle by depending on an interface I don't use.

Instead, I might stop and write an interface:

```
public interface IAddressValidator
{
    ValidationResult ValidateAddress(Address address);
}
```

I inject that interface into my class and keep writing my class, deferring writing an implementation until later.

Then it comes time to implement that class, and that's when I can bring in my other service which was designed with a broader intent than just to service this one class, and adapt it to my interface.

```
public class MyOtherServiceAddressValidator : IAddressValidator
{
    private readonly IOtherServiceInterface _otherService;

    public MyOtherServiceAddressValidator(IOtherServiceInterface otherService)
    {
         _otherService = otherService;
    }

    public ValidationResult ValidateAddress(Address address)
    {
        // adapt my address to whatever input the other service
        // requires, and adapt the response to whatever I want
        // to return.
    }
}
```

`IAddressValidator` exists because I defined it to do what I need for my class, so I never have to worry about having to implement interface members that I don't need. There won't ever be any.

Comment: I think you may be right on in your assessment of the issue.  The approach of housing the abstractions as a separate entity (as shared, common assemblies) from the assemblies that would use them is problematic.  When a method is added to an interface under this scheme, then all the others will sooner or later be prompted to at least stub it out even if they don't use the new method.  This then flies against the interface segregation principle.

Comment: With that then, I'm considering a different approach to abstractions used for DIP in assemblies.  Perhaps the abstractions for the dependencies of a given assembly should be owned by that assembly, not to be shared by other assemblies.  If multiple assemblies use various methods on a class contained in a given assembly, they should have and maintain their own abstractions/interfaces.  As you've said, they won't then have external reason to change.

Comment: With this, local adapter classes would wrap the external dependency, having the dependecy inversion occur in the adapter classes.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the option to version the interfaces; e.g., if there is

```
public interface IDoStuff
{
    void GoFirst();

    void GoSecond();
}
```

There could then be

```
public interface IDoStuffV2 : IDoStuff
{
    void GoThird();
}
```

Then ComponentA can reference `IDoStuff` and ComponentB can be written against `IDoStuffV2`.  Some people frown on interface inheritance, but I don't see any other way to easily version interfaces.